# React Native: How to focus a TextInput wrapped in a custom component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, focus, textinput

In my React Native app I have a custom component that wraps a `TextInput`. In the code that uses the custom component, I want to call `.focus()` on the `TextInput`. I tried calling it directly on the custom component like this:

```
<CustomComponent
  ref={ref => {
    this.customComponent = ref;
  }}
/>

this.customComponent.focus();
```

but I can't because, I assume, custom components don't have a `focus()` method. I could find a way to call it on the wrapped `TextInput`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to call it directly on the custom component.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: You can define focus function in CustomComponent which will call the focus function of TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

if a class component you could use `CustomComponent.prototype.yourFunction()`

`youFunction` uses ref to call `focus()` on `TextInput`

Answer (score 0):

If `CustomComponent` is your own component then in that case you can pass the ref via **[Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)** :

---

Here I have created sample code snippets, which has input inside `CustomComponent` and we can access ref inside that component via `React.forwardRef((props, ref)`

Then we have `createRef` from parent component and pass ref like `<CustomComponent ref={this.ref}>`.

Hope this will help you.

```js
const CustomComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div>
    <input type="text" ref={ref} />
  </div>
));

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.ref.current) {
      this.ref.current.focus();
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Get Focused : 
        <CustomComponent ref={this.ref} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```